# Is it possible to add spring bones on 2 different armatures?

Tags: animation, armature, add-on, bones, physics

I have an animation with 2 models, which means that they have 2 different armatures. I wanna use spring bones for hair, and breast physics. But it seems like when I stop the interactive mode so that the settings can update, the other one suddenly stops but the one I updated works. I've tried to see if I could possibly work around it by selecting an armature and shift clicking the other armature but that didn't seem to work..does anyone know how to fix this?

Example (The part where I paused and circled that area is to show that it clearly has spring bones on, and is working just fine, whereas you can see the other one is staying stretched out and not moving at all, however, has spring bones enabled):
https://gyazo.com/493d15ceb3bbd5044b1d274b1e71b874

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as I know. For my animations, I solved this problem by baking the jiggle onto the bones for armature 1. Once baked, I no longer needed the jiggle to be enabled for armature 1, allowing me to use it on armature 2.

[image: Pose action bake menu]

[image: Bake action confirm for the selected bone (parameters)]

Make sure the "Overwrite Current Action" is ticked, otherwise you will lose all keyframes for the other bones.